# How bad is my HDD for usage?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

I bought an Acer Aspire F5-573G a year ago. It runs on Windows 10 Home x64 and has a 1TB HDD. From the get-go I received my system, I had been experiencing major hiccups in my system performance. The system performance has slowed down quite acutely, and I generally blamed it on the bad HDD, and maybe I was right.

Only recently I heard about a software called HWInfo, and I checked my HDD specs because it had been showing a yellow warning sign on my HDD. I checked the data present, and I was greeted by the following problems :

[image: Number of reallocated logical sectors]

[image: Reallocated sector count]

Comment: This is not an appropriate forum to complain about a vendor. Further, without passing any kind if judgement on Acer, they don't make hard drives - and blame for hard drive problems belong with the hard drive manufacturer. Unfortunately hdd failures are part for the course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 720 reallocated sectors is bad.

Make a backup ASAP, get a new harddisk.

Look at the rest of the SMART attributes, it's possible they sold you a used harddisk.